# JQuery order div by value and skip if value is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've done my ordering in my code but instead of reloading the whole json result, I want a client side reorder for my divs.

My C# code for ordering is:

```cs
.OrderBy(p=> p.order == 0? int.MaxValue : p.order);
```

This give me result like

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 0
- 0
- 0

My Html schema is like

```html
<div class="item" data-sort="0" id="5051fb7c746eed1bf05309db">
 <span>Some values</span>
 <span>Some values</span>
  <div class="subgroups">
    <div class="item" data-sort="null" id="5060de4a746eed1b44cc6e90"></div>
  </div> <!-- closing subgroups -->
</div> <!-- closing main div which need to be sorted -->

<div class="item" data-sort="2" id="5051fb7c746eed1bf05309db">
  <span>Some values</span>
  <span>Some values</span>
  <div class="subgroups">
    <div class="item" data-sort="null" id="5060de4a746eed1b44cc6e90"></div>
  </div> <!-- closing subgroups -->
</div> <!-- closing main div which need to be sorted -->

<div class="item" data-sort="0" id="5051fb7c746eed1bf05309db">
  <span>Some values</span>
  <span>Some values</span>
  <div class="subgroups">
    <div class="item" data-sort="null" id="5060de4a746eed1b44cc6e90"></div>
  </div> <!-- closing subgroups -->
</div> <!-- closing main div which need to be sorted -->
```

How can I reorder these `div`s so that the 2nd one become first and those with 0 data will be last upon reordering.

Comment: There appears to be [a lot of nesting](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/82SJc/) of `div` elements with the `data-sort` attribute. Is that a typo, or intentional? If it's intentional should the nested `div`s be part of the sort, or just the outer elements?

Comment: its intentional couze i hate tables, everything hat i work is divs. I want to order just main divs not sub 'item' divs. Also my sub 'item' divs always have null value for data-sort

Comment: I think you're missing some close `</div>` tags...you close the `subgroups` div, but you don't close the `item` divs....

Comment: [Look at the **JS Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/82SJc/) I linked to in my previous comment, and then explain which of the `div`s are *meant* to be sorted; because I can't see any siblings that should/could be sorted.

Comment: Oh wow, i was confused about "complex nested divs" ... i got an closing div error on my html, ill edit now.. they are not complicated..just single nested div can exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery plugin [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) if you're using jQuery. Here is an example of its use:

```
$(".item").tsort({ attr: 'data-sort',order:'desc'});
```

I think if you can output 0 or -1 instead of null to the data-sort attribute it should put those items at the end.

Comment: huh, this looks like tiny and advanced plugin. I think this gonna solve my problem. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

Put all your divs inside a parent div

```
<div id="parentDiv">
..
</div>
```

Then you can sort like this

```
$(function(){

  function sort_comp(a, b){
    var k1 = parseInt($(a).attr("data-sort"),10);
    if(k1 === 0) k1 = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var k2 = parseInt($(b).attr("data-sort"),10);
    if(k2 === 0) k2 = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    return (k1-k2);
  }

  var arr = $.makeArray($("#parentDiv > .item"));
  arr.sort(sort_comp);
  $("#parentDiv > .item").remove();
  $(arr).each(function(){
    $("#parentDiv").append($(this));
  });
});
```